# Configure Telerik AsyncUpload Control to upload a picture or video file to Third-Party Web Service API?

Tags: web-services, post, asynchronous, upload, telerik

We are uploading media types like pictures and videos to a Third party Companies server by invoking their Web Service API method.

Their Endpoint URI for their Web Service looks similar to the following:

POST https://blah.ThirdPartyFirm.com/v2/blahBlah/media

They require a POST invocation.

Here is how their Request should look like:

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="chunky_bacon.png"
Content-Type: video/mp4
--AaB03x

... contents of omg_pink_ponies.png ...
--AaB03x--

Please show me how to configure the Telerik AsyncUpload Control to upload a picture or a video file to the aforementioned Third-Party Web Service API.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to accomplish this task would be to configure AsyncUpload to use custom handler.
Then once after you have the file's data in the Handler's Process method just send it to the Web API service.

```
                <telerik:RadAsyncUpload
                ID="RadAsyncUpload1"
                OnClientFileUploadFailed="OnClientFileUploadFailed"
                OnClientValidationFailed="OnClientValidationFailed"
                HttpHandlerUrl="~/Handler.ashx"
                runat="server">
            </telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
    <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using Telerik.Web.UI;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

public class Handler : AsyncUploadHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
{
  protected override IAsyncUploadResult Process(UploadedFile file, HttpContext context, IAsyncUploadConfiguration configuration, string tempFileName)
    {
//here send the file to the WebAPI method
//and return custom result to the client
}
}
```

If you are wondering if it is possible to read the file object on the client then you should know that this will be working only for the newer browsers which support HTML5 File API.